# Jquery Multiple Table Rows Divide in separate Pages When Print

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple table like these [1st table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSnQu.png)
[2nd table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAubR.png) 
i want to divide these table rows in separate pages. each page contain 15 or 20 rows, after 1st table complete separating then the 2nd table will start.
these code repeat the head text on next page when print i want to remove it.

please help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("testInfoTable").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("testInfoTable")[i].style.pageBreakBefore = "always";

      }
      var div_pageBreaker = '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>';
      var per_page = 15;
   
      $('.testInfoTable').each(function(index, element) {
        var pages = Math.ceil($(element).find('tbody tr').length / per_page);

         if (pages == 1) {
          return;
        }
        var table_to_split = $(element);

        var current_page = 1;
        
  for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) {
          
    var cloned_table = table_to_split.clone();
          
    $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function(loop, row_element) {
            
   if (loop >= per_page) {
              
     $(row_element).remove();
            }
          });

          
    $('tbody tr', cloned_table).each(function(loop, row_element) {
            
   if (loop < per_page) {
              
     $(row_element).remove();
            }
          });

          
    if (current_page < pages) {
            if (cloned_table.find('tbody tr').length > 0) {
              
     $(element).find(".text").html("What");
    $(cloned_table).find("h4").html("What");
    $(div_pageBreaker).appendTo($(element));
    $(cloned_table).appendTo($(element));
     
            }
          }

          //make a break
          table_to_split = cloned_table;
        }
      });

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <table class="testInfoTable">
    <thead>
  <tr><th> Table 1 Head 1</th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 1 Head 2</div></th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 1 Head 3</div></th> </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 1</h4>
   </th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>3</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>4</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>5</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>6</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>7</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>8</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>9</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>10</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>11</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>12</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>13</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>14</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>15</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>16</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>17</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>18</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>19</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>20</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>21</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>22</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>23</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>24</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>25</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>26</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>27</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>28</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>29</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>30</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>31</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>32</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="testInfoTable">
    <thead>
  <tr><th> Table 2 Head 1</th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 2 Head 2</div></th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 2 Head 3</div></th> </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 2</h4>
   </th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>3</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>4</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>5</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>6</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>7</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>8</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>9</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>10</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>11</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>12</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>13</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>14</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>15</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>16</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>17</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>18</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>19</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>20</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>21</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>22</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>23</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>24</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>25</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>26</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>27</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>28</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>29</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>30</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>31</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>32</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="appendTable"></div>
 </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are looking for "pagination".

Comment: no i am looking for page breaking in table rows for print

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this modification does what you want.

I changed the code so the cloned tables dont´t stays inside the original tables.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var per_page = 15;

    $('.testInfoTable').each(function (index, element) {
        var pages = Math.ceil($(element).find('tbody tr').length / per_page);

        if (pages == 1) {
            return;
        }
        var table_to_split = $(element);

        var current_page = 1;

        for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) {

           var cloned_table = $('<table><tbody>' + table_to_split.find('tbody').html() + '</tbody></table>');

           cloned_table.addClass("testInfoTable cloned")

           $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function (loop, row_element) {

                if (loop >= per_page) {

                    $(row_element).remove();
                }
            });


            $('tr', cloned_table).each(function (loop, row_element) {

                if (loop < per_page) {

                    $(row_element).remove();
                }

            });


            if (current_page < pages) {
           
                table_to_split.after(cloned_table);

                cloned_table.width(table_to_split.width());

            }

            table_to_split = cloned_table;           


        }


    });


    $('<tr><th colspan="3"><h4 class="text">Table Head</h4></th></tr>').prependTo('table.cloned')


});
```

```css
table.testInfoTable {
    page-break-before: always;
    width: 200px;
}

table.testInfoTable td, table.testInfoTable th {

        border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="PRINT" onclick="window.print();" />

<table class="testInfoTable">
<thead>
<tr><th colspan="3"> Table 1 Head 1</th> </tr>
<tr><th colspan="3"> <div>Table 1 Head 2</div></th> </tr>
<tr><th colspan="3"> <div>Table 1 Head 3</div></th> </tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">
<h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 1</h4>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td> <td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>14</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>15</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>16</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>17</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>18</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>19</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>20</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>21</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>22</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>23</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>24</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>25</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>26</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>27</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>28</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>29</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>30</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>32</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="testInfoTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="3"> Table 2 Head 1</th> </tr>
        <tr><th colspan="3"> <div>Table 2 Head 2</div></th> </tr>
        <tr><th colspan="3"> <div>Table 2 Head 3</div></th> </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
                <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 2</h4>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td> <td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>9</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>17</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>18</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>19</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>20</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>21</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>22</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>23</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>24</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>25</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>26</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>27</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>28</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>29</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>30</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>32</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Working example with button to print on this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Leon_Klaj/pnen5g3f/2/

Comment: update it  why  clone table rows width not match with the main table rows. Please Help https://jsfiddle.net/pnen5g3f/7/

Comment: To make this work, the cloned tables can´t be inside the inside original tables.